# Make vs. Do a Video

Tags: word-usage

Is it "make a video" or "do a video"? I feel like both might be correct in an appropriate context but I cannot quite figure out the real difference. Unless it is just one of the two that is correct. I suspect it to be the same difference as "make a movie" and "do a movie". A director usually makes a movie but actors do movies together. But maybe with "video" it's a whole different thing altogether.

Comment: *Do* in English is the all-purpose verb, much the way *thing* is the all-purpose noun. Whatever you may wish to accomplish—build a fire, make love to your honey, pay your taxes, or ask a question on ELU—once the substance of what you wish to happen is understood, you can substitute *do* for the verb. Do it. Do it now. Just do it. Sometimes it gets more basic even than that: the *do* stands in for an inferred verb. "Did you do her?" is a coarse way to ask someone if they've had sex with someone, for example. So you can definitely *do* a video, or a picnic, or an essay, or what have you.

Comment: You can *do a movie* the same way you can *do lunch*: that is, make it a social get-together. On the other hand, when you *make* either, you create it. Or just barely manage to get there on time.

Comment: You can "do" anything today, esp., in AmE.

Comment: Do gets done to death.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The American English corpus on [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+a+video%2Cmake+a+video%2Cdoing+a+video%2Cmaking+a+video&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20a%20video%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20video%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdoing%20a%20video%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaking%20a%20video%3B%2Cc0) suggests that *to make a video* (red) and *making a video* (yellow) are the more common choices

[image]

The form *do* and *doing a video* are acceptable regardless of whether one is appearing  or producing the short film; however, the second use is much less usual. *To make a video* is usually about creating a short film from scratch whereas *to do a video* is to participate, perform or merely appear. As the OP suggested in his question.

> These days pretty much anyone can **make a video** and post it on the Web for the world to see - you don't need anything more complicated than a mobile phone with video-capability and access to a computer.

From a Michael Jackson [biography](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22do%20a%20video%22&lr=lang_en&biw=1024&bih=485&source=lnt&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en%2Ccdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F2002%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2007&tbm=bks#q=%22do%20a%20video%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/2002,cd_max:12/31/2007&tbm=bks&start=0)

> He promised, “I'll never **do a video** like that again! In fact, I have blocked further distribution of the film over which I have control, including its release in some other countries. There's all kinds of promotional stuff being proposed for 'Thriller.

Since the 1980s *make a music video* (red) and *do a music video* (blue) have both been used, the Ngram chart below reflects the frequency of use, which mirrors the chart above.

[image]

In the [following excerpt](https://books.google.it/books?id=zrBolXPYq40C&pg=RA3-PA12-IA9&dq=%22i%20did%20a%20video%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xMuqVM_mC8H8Us_pgcAL&ved=0CD4Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22i%20did%20a%20video%22&f=false), dated 2011, an American director named Marty Callner uses both verbs indiscriminately when talking about directing music videos.

> MARTY CALLNER: I always tried to **make videos** sexy without being sexual. **I did a video** for the Scorpions called “Big City Nights,” and MTV rejected it because there were too many girls in bikinis so I added seven more shots of girls in bikinis and sent it in, and they aired it

However when the topic is *video games* then it is the verb *make* which is always preferred, [*to do a video game*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do%20a%20video%20game%2C%20make%20a%20video%20game&year_start=1960&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20a%20video%20game%3B%2Cc0) is not recorded by Google Ngrams.

Answer (score -1):

Make is to put it together

Do is only the action of acting it out

Answer (score -1):

Make is to create / transform into a form through existing resources.

Do is to follow through the necessary actions required to accomplish something.

Both are correct in this example, but 'do' has a wider scope than 'make'. For example, do could mean anything from 'edit' to 'broadcast'. Make specifically specifies 'create'. However, I would guess that in your situation it's implied.

Answer (score -2):

```
 Use the verb 'do' when speaking about things in general. In other words, when we do not exactly name an activity. This form is often used with the words 'something, nothing, anything, everything, etc.'
 use "do" to refer to jobs, or responsibilties. These are often routine things, which do not involve much creativity or fun.
```

"I do the shopping once a week."

"He does the gardening every weekend."

```
We use "make" for more creative activities:
Constructing, Building, Creating
```

"She makes her own clothes."

"He made a beautiful hat for the wedding."

"She makes food."

```
For more information see below :
```

http://www.english-at-home.com/vocabulary/how-to-use-make-and-do-in-english/
http://esl.about.com/cs/beginner/a/a_makedo.htm

Comment: No explanation.